# Factory methods and private variables

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns, factory

I'm using a factory class to create instances of another class, say the Product class.

How do I set private variables within the Product class from the factory class? Should I even be doing so?

What I'm planning to do is to public setter methods and then freezing or locking the instance once I have finished with it. But I get the feeling this is the Wrong Way to do things.

How would you approach such a problem?

EDIT:

Yes I would like to use @derekerdmann's method of immutable objects. But I probably should give more info first.

I am writing a parser in php for an HTML-like language so you get nodes, which in turn can contain other nodes. So the factory is a parser producing a hierarchy of nodes. If you are curious here is the code http://http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~rhlee/band-parser/dev/view/head:/src/bands.php

The thing is that I don't know what the child nodes will be until I walk down the rest of the document. So I can't pass then to the constructor.

Sometimes I think that even though I *want* it to be read only after parsing, why should it be? I take for example php's DOMDocument parser. You can parse a HTML file, and then still modify the structure. However this is so that you can reproduce the HTML after again with the new changes. My parser is a one-way parser, so the need to edit the structure after parsing is non-existent.

Comment: @derekerdmann is correct. I agree with you that if you plan to at some point 'lock down' changes to the object then setters whose behavior can change are not a very elegant solution. I don't believe a public method should have "gotchya" cases.

Comment: @rdlowrey wouldn't a true/false return for success/failure solve this for all the setters?

Comment: @BrettPontarelli Yes, of you're going to do it that's the right way. I just don't like it for stylistic reasons -- personal OCD/idiosyncrasy :)

Answer (score 3):

The typical way to do this is to create **immutable objects**.  In an immutable object, all private fields are set by passing values into the object's constructor.  Immutable == unmodifiable.

If you do need a way to change the private fields, the setter methods would actually create a new instance with the changed fields.

An example Java class:

```
class ImmutableDuck {

    private final String name;
    private final int age;

    /**
     * Constructor - sets the read-only attributes of the duck
     */
    public ImmutableDuck( String name, int age ){
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public int getAge(){
        return age;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new ImmutableDuck with the current object's age 
     * and the given age
     */
    public ImmutableDuck setName( String name ){
        return new ImmutableDuck( name, age );
    }

}
```

Comment: I'd like to add: Keep in mind collections are mutable, so if you have a getter for a list, you will want the getter to clone the list and return the copy. Failing to do so will result in the list inside the object being cleared if you call `.clear()` on the `getList()` return value.

Comment: Ignore this comment, still getting the hang of stack overflow.

Comment: Unfortunately, I may have to set the fields on my class x number of times. And it just seems a bit expensive to to create a new instance everytime I need to do so.

Comment: To make a variable unmodifiable in Java is not by making it private, but making it final.

Answer (score 0):

I think in a factory situation the solution @derekerdmann has proposed is the correct way.  However, one way to accomplish what @rhlee is asking is to create a "locked" class that requires a `key` to unlock.  A php example:

```
class Thing {
  private $key = '';
  private $name = '';

  public function __construct($key) {
    $this->key = $key;
  }

  public function setName($key, $name) {
    $unlocked = ($this->key == $key);
    if ($unlocked) $this->name = $name;
    return $unlocked;
  }
}
```

Comment: Whoa! I just got hit by a drive-by down vote. ;) Could someone (e.g. the shooter) explain what is wrong with my answer?

Comment: I will upvote your answer, because you show the correct principle, although I would execute it different. I would give the program a one time shot to change the value of a variable and after that not anymore. That implies that whenever a object is created, the registration variable is set, indifferent if all of the other variables are set.

Comment: 10 years later but I though I could advise on why this is not a good idea (I would have done the same myself 10 years ago though). Why provide a key? It feels like the key "protects" the content of `Thing` via a password mechanism but `Thing` is instantiated by code which is the same code that then consumes it so no real benefit. Instead of key you could just have a boolean flag (your `unlocked` in essence). If the object is set to locked and the consumer unlocks it.. well they know they are playing with fire and this is all you generally need. You cannot implement security, only warnings.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly more elegant way is to use package-private constructors and setters.

Example in Java, create a package "x.y.z" and have both classes be in there.

Thing.java:

```
package x.y.z;

public class Thing {

    private int something;

    Thing(final int something) {
        this.something = something;
    }

    void setSomething(final int something) {
        this.something = something;
    }

    public int getSomething() {
        return something;
    }
}
```

ThingFactory.java:

```
package x.y.z;

public class ThingFactory {

    public static Thing createThing() {
        Thing thing = new Thing(1337);
        thing.setSomething(9001);
        return thing;
    }
}
```

You can [read more about member/method access control here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html).

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't thing the same could be done with php namespaces.